# c# regex string,anyone know how?

Tags: c#, regex

i have a text file which contains lots of email addresses from my old address book. I need to get these out of it. every email addy is preceeded with

```
ip:
```

and ends with

```
\
```

for example

```
blablablaip:me@you.com\
```

the addresses are up to 25 characters in length(not sure if that makes a difference for the required regex im a noob) and sometimes there is a line break in the middle of an address, i.e an email address is split between the end of a line and the start of a new line.

Any of you regex wizards offer me any help please?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex :

```
/ip:(.{0,25}?)\/
```

It works like this :

```
/         <- The delimiter of your regex
    ip:       <- Matches the "ip:" part
    (             <- Open a capture group
        .         <- Matches any character 
        {0,25}    <- Last part repeated between 0 and 25 times
        ?         <- Ungreedy modifier, to capture less elements possible (in the 0, 25 limit)
    )         <- End of the capture group
    \         <- The "\" part
/         <- End of the regex
```

In C# you don't need delimiters in your regex so you can use this :

```
@"ip:(.{0,25}?)\\" //Don't forget to escape the \
```

---

**Resources :**

- [regular-expression.info - Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score 0):

regex you're looking for is

```
ip:(.*?)\\
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to strip the line-breaks, just for simplicity.

After that:

```
String regex = @"ip:(?'email'(.*)@(.*\.*))\\";
```

No length restrictions or character restrictions, but it will match the xxx@xx.x part of a email and place it in the email group.